# PHP freezes on sleep()

Tags: javascript, php, xml, xmlhttprequest

I had been testing long-polling for a chat script. I have designed it to work like this :

1. Client sends a request to Server(php)
2. Server gets request, and starts a loop(for 1 min)
3. At every iteration in the loop, the server checks for 'new' messages from database
4. If there is a new message , then server dies with the list of new messages. ( i have used die(string) function
5. That response is received by client, and processed.
6. If there arent any new messages for 1 min, another die() function is run with 'no message' status

the code looks like this :

```
<?php
    while($time<60)
    {

    if(any new messages) {
    die (new messages) 
    }



    sleep(1);
    $time++;

    }

die(no new messages);
```

what this does is, during those 60 seconds(when it is unable to find any new messages) , **my server seems to freeze**. I am unable to open a new page, nor are other users able to access any page (using xampp)
How do I fix this problem ?
I know that this approach might not be so great, but I would like to know the problem , and how to solve it, rather that suggestions on how to get it done using some other way(web sockets,etc)

Comment: How did you identify `sleep` as the culprit? Did it really work without? Otherwise the abstracted code paths, database handling, session usage, etc. might be more relevant.

Comment: When you tested "nor are other users able to access any page" how exactly did you test that?

Comment: I ran that .php. then i tried to run another php from the same server. it didnt open for a very long time

Comment: in the same browser? a different browser? a different tab? If just a different tab, then you're still considered the same user, and your session may still be "locked" if you aren't properly managing the session in the long-polling script.

Comment: If each request goes through that script. Wouldn't it take in the worst case 60 seconds for each request?

Comment: @mario- i have tested everything, it even prints everything as expected, but i have to wait for around a minute to be able to see any new pages

Comment: @KevinB- i tried in the same browser, different browser, AND from the www as well

Comment: @KevinB- for testing purposes, I have not made any sessions in that script

Comment: I noticed something. 
If I try to navigate from the same webpage as the one that issued the request, it seems to freeze